# Debugging on my Android is stuck at "Waiting For Debugger" forever

Tags: android, debugging

This has been asked before here (and other places). Maybe someone will see it and offer a real solution?

I've never had this issue and don't know which application is saying "Waiting for Debugger". I've debugged my C#/Xamarin app on the phone for about 2 years with no problems, until now and now the only way I can "debug" is to put a lot Toasts in my code so at least I know that the code got to a certain point.

I thought that maybe maybe the fact that the USB connection both charges and also is the connection to the computer is the problem. Samsung assistant (a person) told me that charging via USB cannot be turned off.

There must be some way to debug on the Android. At this point my coding has stopped.

RON

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved it. There is a an option Wait for Debugger. It was set to on. I turned it off and now I can debug.

Comment: The answer would be more helpful if you would explain where the option is located... Anyway, why a new question?

Comment: In Developer Options, right in plain view, as it turns out. "Wait for Debugger".